# SQL ORDER BY two fields with priority, rather than one after the other

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

For a message board system. There are general posts, and direct replies to those posts.

```
SELECT * FROM msgs ORDER BY msg_id ASC, msg_replyto ASC
```

will not give me the desired results, because it lists all the general posts, THEN all the replies. I am not sure how to word what I am asking so all I can do is give you mockup table and data.

Here is the example table structure and rows:

```
 msg_id | msg_text                               | msg_replyto
----------------------------------------------------------------
   1    | This is a post ID #1                   | NULL
   2    | This is a post ID #2                   | NULL
   3    | This is a direct reply to post ID #1   | 1
   4    | This is a post ID #4                   | NULL
   5    | This is a post ID #5                   | NULL
   6    | This is a direct reply to post ID #4   | 4
   7    | This is a post ID #7                   | NULL
   8    | This is a direct reply to post ID #3,  | 3
        | which is a direct reply to post ID #1. |
```

The correct order of how I am trying to have the rows returned would be as follows:

```
 msg_id | msg_replyto
-----------------------
   1    | NULL
   3    | 1
   8    | 3
   2    | NULL
   4    | NULL
   6    | 4
   5    | NULL
   7    | NULL
```

Where, at first msg_id has the priority - UNLESS the field msg_replyto in a row is equal to the other row's msg_id, and then msg_replyto has the secondary priority. I am sorry if this doesn't make sense, I have no other way to explain it. I tried searching for this but didn't even know how to word it.

This is the actual SQL to create the example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `msgs` (
  `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msg_text` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `msg_replyto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `msgs` (`msg_id`, `msg_text`, `msg_replyto`) VALUES
(1, 'This is a post ID #1', NULL),
(2, 'This is a post ID #2', NULL),
(3, 'This is a direct reply to post ID #1', 1),
(4, 'This is a post ID #4', NULL),
(5, 'This is a post ID #5', NULL),
(6, 'This is a direct reply to post ID #4', 4),
(7, 'This is a post ID #7 ', NULL),
(8, 'This is a direct reply to post ID #3, which is a direct reply to post ID #1', 3);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MYSQL Version 5.7.31. I also have 8 installed (I'm using WAMPServer on laptop as localhost)

Comment: I added the SQL for the example table and data set. Other than that, I don't see how I didn't follow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to solve this as a general problem.  You have a graph walking problem.

But there is a way.  You can construct a path to each method as a string and then order by that string:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select msg_id, cast(lpad(msg_id, 5, '0') as char(10000)) as path
      from msgs
      where msg_replyto is null
      union all
      select m.msg_id, concat_ws('->', path, lpad(m.msg_id, 5, '0')) 
      from cte join
           msgs m
           on m.msg_replyto = cte.msg_id
     )
select m.*
from msgs m left join
     cte
     on m.msg_id = cte.msg_id
order by cte.path;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edc16124361bca2659b4934fe4cb4a80) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow thanks. Works on 8, throws error on 5.7.x. Is there a less complex way of achieving this, for example creating an entire other table for direct replies (msg_replyto) and creating a UNION or something?

Comment: @EasterEggs . . . MySQL started supporting recursive subqueries in version 8.  There is not really a way to solve this in earlier versions without a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The below should get what you are seeking. It uses a two self joins to join on the msg_replyto value and then orders by msg_id and msg_replyto

```
SELECT C.*
FROM msgs  AS A
LEFT JOIN msgs  AS B
ON A.msg_id = IFNULL(B.msg_replyto,B.msg_id)
JOIN msgs  AS C
ON B.msg_id = IFNULL(C.msg_replyto,C.msg_id)
ORDER BY A.msg_id 
        ,B.msg_id
```

**RESULTS**

| msg_id | msg_text | msg_replyto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is a post ID #1 | NULL |
| 3 | This is a direct reply to post ID #1 | 1 |
| 8 | This is a direct reply to post ID #3, which is a direct reply to post ID #1 | 3 |
| 2 | This is a post ID #2 | NULL |
| 4 | This is a post ID #4 | NULL |
| 6 | This is a direct reply to post ID #4 | 4 |
| 5 | This is a post ID #5 | NULL |
| 7 | This is a post ID #7 | NULL |

Comment: This works somewhat, but the messages that are direct replies to other direct replies are out of order. This returns rows in order 1,3,2,8,4,6,5,7 rather than 1,3,8,2,4,6,5,7

Comment: @EasterEggs - I just modified the code, the above should work for what you need.

Comment: Awesome, thank you sir. I was starting to think I would just have to fudge my PHP code that displays the results, which in my case in undesirable.

Comment: @EasterEggs - Glad I could help :) Please mark my response as the answer if it works for what you need. If you have any further questions feel free to ask.